# OCR Spell Check based upon previously found words

Tags: data-mining, text-mining

I have a bunch of OCR produced text files with numerous spelling errors. I want to automatically correct these spelling based upon the prevalence of the closest correctly spelled words. For example, if the text reads "junp" and the options are "jump" or "june", then it would pick between the two based upon both context and the frequency of the two words. Is there any software like this?